# Displaying MapView in an android device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Actually here I have followed tutorial for Google maps in android sdk using Google play service. But did not get any `MapView` in my real device.please help to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you see a blank screen or squares? Are you sure your API key is set properly?

Comment: simply i got blank screen and yeah,i have used api key

Comment: try to include your code and logcat...

Comment: i followed the link http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-working-with-google-maps-application-setup/

Comment: Version 1 of the Google Maps Android API has been officially deprecated as of December 3rd, 2012.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/hello-mapview

Comment: i have seen your tutorial, its a good one. whats the actual problem. have you checked logcat? your logcat will show the actual problem.

Comment: mostly i didn't get any issues in logcat.i have checked with htc desire device.

Comment: you actually need google play services installed in your device, check if its installed https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must check if Google Play Service is installed in your device

Google Play services is used to update Google apps and apps from Google Play. This component gives you access to Google Settings and helps apps speed up offline searches, provide more immersive maps, and improve performance.
Apps may not work if you uninstall Google Play services. You probably need this component.

Get it [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms)

Answer (score 2):

Google maps for android is maps v2. Google maps v2 does not suppot mapview anymore(if you have an old api key it will work for maps v1, but if you need a new key they stopped the service). So I suggest you move on to maps v2 and make use of the below code or make use of the tutorial mentioned below the code

```
// Getting Google Play availability status
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());                
if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available
int requestCode = 10;
Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, requestCode);
dialog.show();
}

else 
{ // Google Play Services are available     

// Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
SupportMapFragment fragment = ( SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);

// Getting Google Map
mGoogleMap = fragment.getMap();
```

=============================================

you may also follow this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html

Comment: very thanks for your guidance for getting mapview and am getting map view over my application @Balavishnu.