# why Can't I see the map

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I want to run demo Google map but it is not showing map. Here is my code.I have checked API key it is correct

```
package com.example.googlemaps;
import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return true;
    }

}
```

Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.googlemaps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.androidhive.googlemaps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

layout xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="@string/Api_key"
/>
```

Comment: i faced same problem but i used `SupportMapFragment`, [here](http://www.truiton.com/2013/05/android-supportmapfragment-example/) is the example.

Comment: @MrSuS from last 3 to 4 hour i am strugling.i dont wat jump directly to mapfragment I want to learn from ground level..

Comment: Have you imported and included google-play-services-lib as an library dependency for your app? [Here's](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html#maps_device) a great tutorial explaining everything.

Comment: take a look this link,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17895658/displaying-mapview-in-an-android-device/17895759?noredirect=1#comment26217641_17895759

Comment: @ErikSoderstrom I imported google-play-services-lib ,without import it'll show error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is old way for getting map. Google has updated it now. 
use

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
```

in your xml layout.

provide your API key in manifest file as

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="YOUR-API-KEY" />
```

in your application tag.

also don't extend `MapActivity`. Instead extend normal `Activity`

then write below code in your OnCreate

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,
                requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    } else {
        // Google Play Services are available

        // Getting reference to the SupportMapFragment
        SupportMapFragment fragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        // Getting Google Map
        myMap = fragment.getMap();

        // Enabling MyLocation in Google Map
        myMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        // Getting LocationManager object from System Service
        // LOCATION_SERVICE
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Getting the name of the best provider
        String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Getting Current Location From GPS
        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            onLocationChanged(location);
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
    }
```

also add following code on OnResume

```
int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil
                .isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());

    if (resultCode == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {

    } else {
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                RQS_GooglePlayServices);
    }
```

that's it.
All the best!

Answer (score 1):

Version 1 googlemaps officially depricated.so just use version 2 and add google-play-services libs.surely it will help to get googlemap.

1. public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity  {
       protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

   ```
   mGoogleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
       .getMap();    } }
   ```

---

1. ```
   <uses-sdk
       android:minSdkVersion="8"
       android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

   <permission
       android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
       android:protectionLevel="signature" />

   <uses-feature
       android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
       android:required="true" />

   <uses-permission android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
   ```

   />

   ```
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
       <activity
           android:name="com.vogella.android.locationapi.maps.MainActivity"
           android:label="@string/app_name" >
           <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

               <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
           </intent-filter>
       </activity>

       <meta-data
           android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
           android:value="AIzaSyDeYchyvOUsy_I68_RMtfsI5QVkqweIp9w" />
   </application>
   ```

---

1. ```
   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
   ```

   1. refer this link,http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidGoogleMaps/article.html